# About Ito's isometry application

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I've been re-reading one passage from the book of Bernt Øksendal for a whole week and still can't understand one moment in proof of that theorem:

> Lemma 6.2.7.: $\hat{X_t} = E[X_t] +
> \int_{0}^{t}\frac{\partial}{\partial s} E[X_tR_s]\, dR_s $

My question about this moment:

> $E[X_t\int_{0}^{t}f(s)\, dR_s] = E[\hat{X_t}\int_{0}^{t}f(s)\, dR_s] =
> > E[\int_{0}^{t}g(s)\,dR_s \int_{0}^{t}f(s)\, dR_s] =
> > E[\int_{0}^{t}g(s)f(s)\, ds]$
>
> for all $f$ from $L^2[0,t]$

I understand, that $E[\int_{0}^{t}g(s)f(s)\, ds]$ they got from $E[\int_{0}^{t} g(s)f(s) \, dRs]$ by Ito's isometry.

But how did they get this $E[\int_{0}^{t} g(s)f(s) \,dRs]$ from $E[\int_{0}^{t} g(s)\,dRs \int_{0}^{t} f(s)\, dRs]$? I cant understand only this step here.

definitions:

> $dR_s = \frac{1}{D(t)} dN_t(\omega); t \ge0, R_0=0,N_t - $ innovation
> process $N_t$: $N_t = Z_t - \int_{0}^{t} G(s)\hat{X_s} \,ds$
>
> $G(t),D(t) \in \mathbb{R}$ - functions from representation of linear
> observations:
>
> $dZ_t = G(t)X_tdt + D(t)dV_t$, $V_t$ - Brownian motion
>
> $\hat{X_t}$ is projection of $X_t$ on $L(R,t) $space

Comment: If I may, You should consider correcting your post. It contains many issues and typos. I am confident that someone would take time to answer you if your post was better written.

Comment: What?  What typos and issues are you talking about?  I already fixed my question,  but still nobody answered. I think,  just nobody really want to dig at such specified area.

Comment: After Lemma 6.2.7: "+>" doesn't make sens,  You also have these "=>" which aren't making sens where they are, $\hat{X}$ is not defined ect....

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this typo, editor of the site spoiled my text. Okay, i also added definition of X_hut, but you know, there were common known definitions in math,  and i saw question with exactly the same terms,  which my question has, but without *any* definitions, and you know, they had answers. And generally,  i rarely see any questions with any definitions here. But okay,  it's not the big point.

Comment: Well... anyway... What you seek can be deduced from Ito isometry applied to $(\int_0^t f(s)+g(s) \ dR_s)^2$.

Comment: I don't see,  how can it help me, but thanks